# Apply glm to iris dataset in caret R

Tags: r, r-caret

I try to apply the glm algorithm on the Iris dataset, using the following code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(caret)

dataset <- iris
tt_index <- createDataPartition(dataset$Sepal.Length, times = 1, p = 0.9, list = FALSE)
train_set <- dataset[tt_index, ]
test_set <- dataset[-tt_index, ]

model_glm <- train(Species ~., 
                   data = train_set,
                   method = "glm")
```

But it returned me this alert:

```
Something is wrong; all the Accuracy metric values are missing:
    Accuracy       Kappa    
 Min.   : NA   Min.   : NA  
 1st Qu.: NA   1st Qu.: NA  
 Median : NA   Median : NA  
 Mean   :NaN   Mean   :NaN  
 3rd Qu.: NA   3rd Qu.: NA  
 Max.   : NA   Max.   : NA  
 NA's   :1     NA's   :1
```

Perhaps I am missing something, please your help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to train a binary (i.e. binomial) classification model to data with a response variable that has more than 2 levels. The warnings that you are getting and that you can see if you type `warnings()` will tell you that

> glm models can only use 2-class outcomes

So this won't work.

An option is to omit one of the outcomes, e.g. do

```r
dataset <- subset(iris, Species != "virginica")
dataset <- transform(dataset, Species = droplevels(Species))

tt_index <- createDataPartition(
    dataset$Sepal.Length, times = 1, p = 0.5, list = FALSE)
train_set <- dataset[tt_index, ]
test_set <- dataset[-tt_index, ]

model_glm <- train(
    Species ~.,
    data = train_set,
    method = "glm",
    family = "binomial")
```

This will still give warnings, but they have a different origin. Bottom line is, that this is probably not a very good example for testing `glm`-based binomial classification.

Comment: Hello @Maurits Evers, first thank you for your time in giving the answer, I didn't know that `glm` couldn't handle multiclass outcomes.

Comment: @Alexis You're very welcome. In the example, you're (trying to) fit a simple binomial model to data with `glm` along the lines of `glm(class_with_two_outcomes ~ ., data = df, family = "binomial")`. To allow for >2 classes you need a multinomial model. For example, you could do `model_multinom <- train(Species ~., data = train_set, method = "multinom")` to fit a penalised multinomial regression model.

Comment: That was a great explanation @Maurits Evers!, I applied the `multinom` method and voilá, it converged to an accuracy of 95%. Now I have to investigate how to get rid of all the text that shows the iterations. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Alexis. Again, you're very welcome, glad it was useful. Regarding additional output messages, you may want to look into `suppressMessages` and/or `suppressWarnings`. Or if you're compiling an RMarkdown document, you might want to play around with `message=FALSE` and/or `warning=FALSE` in the code chunk options.